# How to change button image when clicked in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, button

How would you make it when a button is clicked the image that the button is made of will change?

```
   #button {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;

    }

   #button:focus {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background-image: url('qmb2.png');

    }


   <input type="image" src="qmb.png" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" id="button" height="49.5px" padding = "0px" />
```

Comment: Please reformulate your question. It is quite hard to understand in its current form.

Comment: Can you provide an example of anything you have already tried? Would this be simply client-side or after a request has been sent to the server and returned?

Comment: I edited it to what I have already tried

Comment: @MaxR why do you not upvote your answers? upvotes cost nothing?

Comment: Also not even grading an answer that satisfies your needs...?

Comment: sorry, none of them satisfied my needs but I will still give you both an upvote for your help.

Comment: Maybe describe what you need to happen a bit better/differently?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery

```js
$("#flowers").click(function () {
    var _this = $(this);
    var current = _this.attr("src");
    var swap = _this.attr("data-swap");
    _this.attr('src', swap).attr("data-swap",  current);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='flowers' class="full" src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg' width="500" height="400" data-swap='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg'  width="500" height="400" />
```

Using Javascript

```css
img{height:400px; width:500px}
```

```html
<script>
    function swap()
{
    if (document.pic.src=='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg'){

document.pic.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg';
} 
else if (document.pic.src=='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg'){

document.pic.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg';
}
}
</script>
<img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg" name="pic" onclick="swap()"/>
```

Using pure mouseover/mouseout

```css
img{height:400px; width:500px}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg" 
onMouseOver="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg';"
onMouseOut="this.src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg';">
```

Comment: does the images i want to replace the first image with go in the else if statement?

Comment: fiddle for mouseover http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/qz19sfts/  fiddle for javascript http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/tyfstasn/

Answer (score 1):

Here is pure JavaScript, if JQuery is out of the question...

```
<input type="image" id="button" name="img" src="firefox.ico" width="50" />
<script>
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.setAttribute("src", "chrome.ico");
    });
</script>
```

Not that I have something against Rachel's answer on pure JavaScript use, but I just feel there could be something more reader-friendly written to toggle the image, such as:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var path;
    if(this.getAttribute("src") === "firefox.ico")
        path = "chrome.ico";
    else
        path = "firefox.ico";
    this.setAttribute("src", path);
});
```

IMO is a little bit cleaner-ish, and it's really not advised to use `onclick` properties in html, but rather implement listeners via JavaScript.

Comment: what goes in the "chrome.ico"

Comment: the path to the image you want to put in instead of the original (qmb.png in your case)

Comment: so would i just put the name of that image in the "chrome.ico"

Comment: if the page is located in the same folder, yes. But if the html is in folder `site` and your images are located in folder `site/images`, you have to relocate your path, like so: `site/images/chrome.ico` (or whatever your image name is). This kind of pathing is called `relative pathing` [see here](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery, when you click first time the class cliked will be added.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').on('click', function(){
$(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
});
```

And css:

```
Button{
Background: img1.jpg;

}
Button.clicked{
Background: img2.jpg;
}
```